# Can you use 或者 to express alternatives between more options than two?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, usage, sentence-structure, conjunction

In all the examples I have come across, [或者](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_%22or%22_in_statements) is always used to express the **conjunction *or* between two options in statements**.

My question is **if you can still use it between three or more options**. That is, is it possible to do the following structure?

> ... option 1, option 2, 或者 option 3.

Otherwise, how could you express this in Chinese?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. What we usually put is something like:

> 你可以给我A, 或者B, 或者C, 或者D.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but I think (要)不然 is better.

- 你選擇誰 - 大明,或(者)小明,(要)不然大衛? "Who you chose - 大明 or 小明, (if neither) how about 大衛?"
- 你想要什麼 - 橘子,或(是)香蕉,(要)不然蘋果? "What do you want - orange or banana, (if not) how about an apple?)
- 父親對女兒說: 妳可選擇上大學或者大專, 要不然棄讀書去就業. "A father says to his daughter: You can choose to go on to study in the university or a trade college, if neither (otherwise), you can abandon/give up your books and look for work instead."
- 鱼有多種吃法, 煎或(是)煮, 要不然燉湯, 再不然(就)做生鱼片.

Note: 或是 = 或者. It can also make a good sentence with the form 1 或者 2, 或是 3.

Word in parentheses can be omitted.

Comment: ah, I meant 或者 in statements (not in questions). Is it still the same? (I thought in questions you had to use 还是 instead of 或者).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.
If there are three options, you can also say A或者B，再或者C。再=again
You can also use还是： A, B, 还是C？
或者is formal, 还是is less formal